# Combining two dicts into one dict

Tags: python, function, dictionary

I'm trying to combine two dicts into one, in which the keys are the first dict values and the values are the second keys values. if one of the arguments is'nt a dict the func need to return: "Input must be a dictionary"

for example:

```
dict1 = {'ZIM': 'Zimbabwe'}
dict2 = {'ZIM': {'Gold': 3, 'Silver': 4, 'Bronze': 1, 'Total': 8}}
```

the output I wish to get is:

```
comb_dict = {'Zimbabwe': {'Gold': 3, 'Silver': 4, 'Bronze': 1, 'Total': 8}}
```

I tried to do it in two different ways which didnt work..
first try:

```
def switch_to_full_name(dict1,dict2):
comb_dict = {}
if isinstance(dict1, dict) and isinstance(dict2, dict):
    keys = dict1.values()
    comb_dict = {k:dict1[v] for k,v in dict2.items() if v in keys}
else:
    return "Input must be a dictionary"
print(comb_dict)
```

and the output is this:

```
{}
None
```

my second try went like that:

```
def switch_to_full_name(dict1,dict2):
comb_dict = {}
if isinstance(dict1, dict) and isinstance(dict2, dict):
    comb_dict[dict1.values()] = comb_dict[dict2.values()]
else:
    return "Input must be a dictionary"
print(comb_dict)
```

and I got this error in the output:

```
KeyError: dict_values([{'Gold': 0, 'Silver': 0, 'Bronze': 2, 'Total': 2},
```

appreciate any kind of help, Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so to get the expected output from your specific defined input, you can do:

```py
dict(zip(dict1.values(), dict2.values()))
# output => {'Zimbabwe': {'Gold': 3, 'Silver': 4, 'Bronze': 1, 'Total': 8}}
```

but it is really depends on your data structure, please check.

Answer (score 0):

```
dict1 = {'ZIM': 'Zimbabwe'} dict2 = {'ZIM': {'Gold': 3, 'Silver': 4, 'Bronze': 1, 'Total': 8}}

def switch_to_full_name(dict1, dict2):
    comb_dict = {}
    if isinstance(dict1, dict) and isinstance(dict2, dict):
        comb_dict = {list(dict1.values())[0]: value for key, value in dict2.items()}
        return comb_dict
    else:
        return "Input must be a dictionary"



print(switch_to_full_name(dict1, dict2))
```

One of your problems was that the function did not return a combined dictionary

Comment: Thats right, but what if dict1 had more the one key and value? that func only returns the first key in the dict or am I wrong?

Comment: Yes, that func only returns the first key in the dict.